# Stop looping in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have had a look through Stack overflow and cant see something similar to this. I have tried a few things and still cannot get it to work.

I am trying to display something else after this piece of code, but it does not appear. When I move it above this piece of code it works fine so I think that the code below is still lopping. Can some one please tell me how I can stop the loop and then continue to display what I need to display.

Thanks.

the code is as follows that I need to stop looping

```
<?php $pst = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 2, 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' )); foreach($pst as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <li>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('testimonial-thumb'); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <h5><?php the_field('testimonial_name'); ?>
    <span><?php the_field('testimonial_job_position'); ?>, <?php the_field('testimonial_company'); ?></span>
    </h5>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Post the code that you want to go after this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information to accurately diagnose your problem but based on the fact that it works above the `foreach` but not after, it seems likely that your problem is related to the global `$post` object in Wordpress.

Try adding `wp_reset_postdata();` AFTER the `endforeach;` line.

This will restore the `$post` object to the one for that page, rather than for the last of the post objects returned by `get_posts()`.  Essentially it just cleans up after the `setup_postdata()` call.  Without doing this, template tags and functions that rely on the `$post` object will not function as expected.